# Call aspx page from silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, crystal-reports

I want to call aspx page from my silverlight application. I kept that aspx page in .Web part of my silverlight application so that i can use crystal reports in my silverlight application.

My code for calling that asp.net page in silverlight page is

```
private void bttnGenerateReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboBranch.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {

            Uri myUri = null;

            myUri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, String.Format("Reports/ConcurrentReport.aspx?PlanCode={0}&BranchCode={1}", PlanCode, BranchCode));
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri, "_blank");
        }
    }
```

but i am getting the error at HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(myUri, "_blank") as "Access is denied" .. invalidoperationexception was unhandled

i am using Windows 7 and IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem got resolved , actually my web project was not the startup project infact the silverlight project was the startup project thus the url had file system path and that was causing "access denied".

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another option to navigate to a server side script (ASPX, ASHX). 1) Make sure you have Hyperlink button in your XAML with NavigateURL property not set 2) Set target to new page "_blank" 3) Assign NavigateURL property post initializecomponent() call